# Help with this LINQ to SQL query

Tags: linq, linq-to-sql, select

I have the following query:

```
var content = (from ca in db.ContentAccesses 
               where !candidateList.Contains(ca.Content) &&
                     ca.DateAccessed >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)
               group ca by ca.ContentId)
               .OrderByDescending(c => c.Count()).Take(5);
```

Which is resolving to the following T-SQL

```
SELECT TOP (5) [t1].[ContentId] AS [Key]
FROM (
    SELECT COUNT(*) AS [value], [t0].[ContentId]
    FROM [dbo].[ContentAccesses] AS [t0]
    WHERE (NOT ([t0].[ContentId] = @p0)) AND ([t0].[DateAccessed] >= @p1)
    GROUP BY [t0].[ContentId]
    ) AS [t1]
ORDER BY [t1].[value] DESC
```

But I need the actual "Content" objects, not just the ContentId's... so I've tried adding `select ca.Content` after the `group by` but compiler will complain.

ContentAcceses has a FK (ContentId) to Content table.

I don't understand LINQ quite well yet.

Comment: What you mean by "actual "Content" objects" ? All the columns ? You can't group by and get all the columns in table.

Comment: Yes, but I'm grouping the ContentAcceses table, which has the FK. I got the ids I need, I just need to do get the Content objects which ids are returned in that query, without dropping another query.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You need to flatten the groupings down to get the individual objects from the group.  However since you wanted to group each `ContentAccess`'s `Content`, you should group by that as well.

```
var content = (from ca in db.ContentAccesses 
               where !candidateList.Contains(ca.Content)
                  && ca.DateAccessed >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)
               group ca by ca.ContentId into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               from ca in g        // flatten the group
               select ca)
              .Take(5);
```

For the sake of having a simpler equivalent TSQL query, you might want to use LINQ to Objects to do the flattening and get the first 5.

```
var content = (from ca in db.ContentAccesses 
               where !candidateList.Contains(ca.Content)
                  && ca.DateAccessed >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)
               group ca by ca.ContentId into g
               orderby g.Count() descending
               select g)
              .AsEnumerable()     // use LINQ to Objects
              .SelectMany(g => g) // flatten the group
              .Take(5);
```

Comment: Great, nice and clean, except I needed to do 'select ca.Content' instead of just ca. Thank you =)

Comment: @emzero: Oh so `Content` is just a column in a `ContentAccess`?  Then you should group those instead.  I'll update my queries.

Comment: No, 'Content' is another table which is referenced in 'ContentAcceses' by a FK called 'ContentId'.

Comment: @emzero: In that case, I'll just revert to how it was.  As long as it leads you to the answer.

Comment: Yeah, it works, although the sql generated is a bit odd, but I can live with it.

Answer (score 0):

```
var content =  (from ca in db.ContentAccesses 
               where !candidateList.Contains(ca.Content) &&
                     ca.DateAccessed >= DateTime.Now.AddDays(-90)
               group ca by ca.ContentId into cag
               select new
               {
                 ContentId = cag.Key,
                 Contents = cag
               }).OrderByDescending(c => c.Contents.Count()).Take(5);
```

Comment: Thanks, but I prefer not to create anonymous objects, besides 'cag' doesn't contain the Content objects, it's just the Key/Count group.